# inheritance using parent class method without calling parent class

Tags: python, inheritance

Is there any way to access parent class method, without actually calling the class?

e.g.:

1)

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('A class')

    def name():
        print('name from A class')
```

2)

```
class B(A):
    # I want to make use of name without actually calling or running A.
    # Is there any way to do that?
```

Comment: *use of name without actually calling or running A* - how are you going to use/call the `name()` method without actually calling it?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can just call it directly. This works fine:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('A class')

    def name(self):
        print('name from A class')

class B(A):
    pass

B().name()

> A class
> name from A class
```

You can also use it inside of the class, like

```
class B(A):
    def b_name(self):
        print('I am B!')
        self.name()
```

If what you're trying to get around is calling A's `init`, then maybe you should turn `name` into a classmethod:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('A class')

    @classmethod
    def name(self):
        print('name from A class')

A.name()

> name from A class
```

Alternatively, you can give B an `init` which doesn't call its super class, thus instantiating it without calling A's init. I don't particularly recommend this method:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('A class')

    def name(self):
        print('name from A class')

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('B class')

    def b_name(self):
        print('b_name from B class')
        self.name()

B().b_name()

> B class
> b_name from B class
> name from A class
```

Comment: but i am working on my college project which is big and complicated to explain.
what i want is to call B().name without actually giving to __init__ of A()

Comment: If you're just trying to avoid the init, maybe make `name` a classmethod?

Comment: If that's not an option, you *can* call `name` without going through A's init, but it's not really recommended. If you create an `init` method for B which does not call its superclass, then a B instance is created without calling A's init, and then you can call `name` from it.

Comment: well sounds like i can use that
can you please post a sample code that will be really helpful.